# miyodeya.com/users/login doesn't work anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

When logging in to MY, I usually used `miyodeya.com/users/login`, just because it's easier to type than `judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login`, and faster than going to miyodeya.com and clicking my way through to the login page.

For some reason, when I tried to access `miyodeya.com/users/login`, I wasn't able to log in from there -- that address took me to `http://judaism.stackexchange.com//users/login`, and claimed that the page did not exist. `judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login` still works.

Please fix!

Comment: There's likewise an error for [`yodeya.com/users/login`](http://yodeya.com/users/login) and [`mi.yodeya.com/users/login`](http://mi.yodeya.com/users/login).

Comment: @msh210 ... and for [`mi.yodeya.com/q/1`](http://mi.yodeya.com/q/1) and [`mi.yodeya.com/questions/1`](http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/1). This is a big deal, as it breaks many links to our content out there in the wild, including all of the ones in [MY Publications](http://s.tk/miyodeya) and nearly everything tweeted to date by the [@mi_yodeya twitter account](http://twitter.com/mi_yodeya).

Comment: Previously: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/mi-yodeya-com-path-urls-strip-the-path-on-redirecting http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1956/yodeya-com-down ... Did the DNS configurations for `yodeya.com` (and its `mi` subdomain) and `miyodeya.com` change recently?

Comment: It [looks like](http://httpstatus.io/) the DNS setting is still a 301 to `http://judaism.stackexchange.com`, but with a superfluous trailing `/`.

Comment: [`seasonedadvice.com/q/1`](http://seasonedadvice.com/q/1) is still fine.

Comment: This appears to have been fixed now.

Comment: See also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3670